# html outlook links not clickable

Tags: html, email, outlook, newsletter

I'm working on a newsletter which you can find here:

http://www.conrad-stanen.nl/nieuwsbrief/12_2015/

All links are working correctly. Including the ones on the right with the text boxes and images.

Sending this HTML format as an email works with postbox for Mac, but for Windows outlook 2013, it blocks most of the links in the right column meaning that the links are not clickable.

I've tried using Mailchimp with a template, but it still gives the errors.

This would be a whole article with the links included:

```
<tr id="article1">
<td width="400">

    <table cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" width="441">

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="right" height="18" valign="top">
                <font face="Arial" style="font-size: 16px" color="#000000">
                    Conrad op Bauma beurs M&uuml;nchen 2016!
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="15" valign="middle" colspan="3">
                <img border="0" src="http://www.conrad-stanen.nl/nieuwsbrief/12_2015/images/yellow.jpg" width="100%" height="7">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <p style="text-align: justify;">
                    <font face="Arial" style="font-size: 12px" color="#000000">
                        <b>
                            De Bauma beurs is de grootste en meest toonaangevende beurs op het gebied van bouwmachines, mijnbouw machines, constructie machines, grondboormachines. etc. De beurs is afwisselend in Duitsland, China of Amerika.
                        </b>
                        <br>
                    </font>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="224">
                <p style="text-align: justify; width: 224px;">
                    <font face="Arial" style="font-size: 12px" color="#000000">
                        In 2016 is de beurs weer in Duitsland en Conrad Stanen zal hier aanwezig zijn met een eigen stand! Wij zullen hier een aantal van onze nieuwere modellen gaan presenteren, zodat ook de rest van de wereld kennis kan maken met onze unieke en innovatief hoogstaande grondboormachines. Wij hopen natuurlijk veel (toekomstige) klanten te verwelkomen op de beurs en op onze stand. 
                        <br><br>
                        Komt u ook kijken wat wij u te bieden hebben? 
                        <a href="http://www.conrad-stanen.nl/nieuwsartikel.asp?nid=62" target="_blank" style="color:#000000;">
                            <font face="Arial" style="font-size: 12px" color="#000000">
                                Lees meer &raquo;
                            </font>
                        </a>
                    </font>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="top" width="161" align="right">
                <a href="http://www.conrad-stanen.nl/nieuwsartikel.asp?nid=62" target="_blank">
                <img border="0" src="http://www.conrad-stanen.nl/nieuwsbrief/12_2015/images/bauma-nieuwsbrief.jpg" width="161" height="107" alt="Conrad op Bauma beurs München"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</td>
```

And this would be the link that's not clickable:

```
<a href="http://www.conrad-stanen.nl/nieuwsartikel.asp?nid=62" target="_blank" style="color:#000000;">
                                                                    <font face="Arial" style="font-size: 12px" color="#000000">
                                                                        Lees meer &raquo;
                                                                    </font>
                                                                </a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "blocks"? What error are you getting?

Comment: It's not clickable. Yet in browser it is.

Comment: Can you edit some relevant code intp the question for future generations?

Comment: Also can you provide an example of a link that isn't working? To avoid confusion.

Comment: Added some of the code for you @Pekka. Won't add all because it'd be unreadable because of too many tables, tr's and td's

Comment: Maybe it's a security mechanism blocking things because you're setting the colour inside the link using the `font` tag? What happens if you remove that?

Comment: That would be weird, I'm not using any anti-virus program and windows firewall is off. And that beside, I'm also colouring the links on the left if you look on the page and they work fine in the email.

Comment: Maybe it's Outlook itself? I'd try it out. (The `font` tag has no use these days anyway, and is superfluous where you are using it.)

Comment: Removed the font tag, unfortunately that isn't working. Still not clickable in the email.

Comment: Strange. So it's working for some, and for some it isn't? If it didn't work for *all* links it could be this http://www.timeatlas.com/outlook-hyperlinks-fail-to-work/

Comment: did you remove all font tags as you have one outside the link and one inside the link

Comment: Yes I tried @Pete  
I'm currently trying to rebase the whole right side of the newsletter. WHen I know more I'll let you guys know. Thanks for all the input!

Comment: I've noticed another strange thing about this, when scrolling a bit up and down it works. Then after some time it just goes unclickable again.

Comment: Get rid of all the `font` tags. That tag is deprecated.

Comment: Outlook has lots of idiosyncrasies and annoying quirks. Because it's happening in a whole section, I would make sure that you've correctly closed and opened all tags as that would always cause strange issues when I used to create e-mail templates.

Comment: @APAD1 E-mail is ~10 years behind web standards. Most mail user agents aren't modern enough to follow the latest conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@APAD1 @AlexW I've fixed it. There were so many td's and tr's that somehow we placed one too many, my collegue at my work looked at it and had it fixed within 15 minutes.

**Conclusion:** always check your tags. **Even if your IDE says nothing is wrong.** 80% chance that if someone has the similar problem as I do that this could be the solution.

*Thanks everyone for their input, it's greatly appreciated.*

Comment: I changed this line http://www.conrad-stanen.nl/nieuwsbrief/12_2015/images/bauma-nieuwsbrief.jpg with this line C:\MyPicture.png. But MyPicture doesnt viewed in the mail. Do you know why?